# Return unknown duplicates from a table

Tags: sql

for eg Table 1

```
transaction----------------Amount------------------date           

Premium billed              250                   20160202
Premium billed              150                   20160205
Premium billed              250                   20160202
```

Table 2

```
Reference no

001
002
003
```

I need to join the two tables and return the reference number on table 2 that has duplicates

NOTE: transaction can be done on any date I need to find the duplicates so the date is unknown.

This is what i have tried:

```
SELECT refno, 
       a.movementdate 
FROM   lif_mgm_t_contract a WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT transactiontypeid, 
                      movementdate, 
                      movementcount, 
                      a.movementdate, 
                      refno 
               FROM   lif_tms_t_financialtransaction 
               WHERE  transactiongroupid = 1 
                      AND isbillingtrx = 1 
                      AND amount > 0 
                      AND a.movementdate = movementdate 
               GROUP  BY movementdate 
               HAVING Count (movementcount) > 1)
```

Comment: Join on which column(s), duplicates according to what column(s)? What rdbms are you using?

Comment: reference number to table 1 hope im making sense

Comment: No, the sample data you've shown does not show the reference number of table 2 in table 1. Is there anything that you've tried yourself? If so, show your approach.

Comment: Or it can pick it up if the amount is the same but I have different amounts on the table so I need to pick up duplicates with the same amount and same date

Comment: yes I wrote something'

Comment: Select refno, a.MovementDate from LIF_MGM_T_Contract a with (nolock)
where exists
(
 Select transactiontypeid,MovementDate,MovementCount,a.MovementDate, RefNo from  LIF_TMS_T_FinancialTransaction
 where TransactionGroupID =1 and IsBillingTrx = 1 and amount > 0 
 and a.MovementDate = MovementDate
 group by MovementDate
 having count (movementcount) > 1
)

Comment: how are table 1 and table 2 related? column name?